# How can i use Maple(or any other software) to rearrange any equation into another equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maple, wolfram-alpha

Let's say I have some equation $= x^2+y=3$. I want to somehow rearrange this into something else such as $x=({\rm root}(3-y) z)/z$. I solved for x and multiplied z above and below. Can Maple (or some other software) show me steps to convert the equation $x^2+y=3$ into $x=({\rm root}(3-y) z)/z$?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

In Maple, you could get a verbose set of steps with,

```
Student:-Basics:-SolveSteps(x^2+y=3, x)
```

Comment: This would just solve the equation for x. What if i want to convert this equation to another equation such as 'x=(root(3−y)z)/z' and see the steps to do that?